# Python scrapy with authentication or cookies

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following web crawler script which is work correctly,
What I need is a way to integrate authentication or sending cookies in each requests

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
class TheFriendlyNeighbourhoodSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'TheFriendlyNeighbourhoodSpider'    
    allowed_domains = ['one.google.com']
    start_urls = ['https://one.google.com/about']   
    custom_settings = {
    'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO'
    }
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )
    def parse_item(self, response):
        print(response.url)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
request_with_cookies = Request(url="http://www.example.com",
                           cookies=[{'name': 'currency',
                                    'value': 'USD',
                                    'domain': 'example.com',
                                    'path': '/currency'}])
```

For more info: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html